# Find greater row between two dataframes of same shape

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of the same shape and am trying to find all the rows in df A where *every value* is greater than the corresponding row in df B.

Mini-example:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'one':[20,7,2],'two':[11,9,1]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,8,12],'two':[10,5,3]})
```

I'd like to return only row 0.

```
    one     two
0   20      11
```

I realise that `df_A > df_B` gets me most of the way, but I just can't figure out how to return only those rows where everything is `True`.

(I tried merging the two, but that didn't seem to make it simpler.)

Comment: Could you also add the expected output for the example?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_A.loc[(df_A > df_B).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUIC, you can use `all`

```
In [633]: m = (df_A > df_B).all(1)

In [634]: m
Out[634]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

In [635]: df_A[m]
Out[635]:
   one  two
0   20   11

In [636]: df_B[m]
Out[636]:
   one  two
0    1   10

In [637]: pd.concat([df_A[m], df_B[m]])
Out[637]:
   one  two
0   20   11
0    1   10
```

Or, if you just need row indices.

```
In [642]: m.index[m]
Out[642]: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the 1 in `all(1)` for column axis was what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.DataFrame({"one": [20, 7, 2], "two": [11, 9, 1]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({"one": [1, 8, 12], "two": [10, 5, 3]})

row_indices = (df_A > df_B).apply(min, axis=1)

print(df_A[row_indices])
print()
print(df_B[row_indices])
```

Output is:

```
   one  two
0   20   11

   one  two
0    1   10
```

Explanation:

`df_A > df_B` compares element wise, this is the result:

```
     one    two
0   True   True
1  False   True
2  False  False
```

Pythons `max` interprets `True` > `False`, so applying `min` row wise (this is why I used `axis=1`) only computes `True` if both values in a row are `True`:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
```

This is now a boolean index to extract rows from  `df_A` resp. `df_B`.

Comment: This is interesting, could you just elaborate on why `min` only returns all-true rows? why wouldn't it return all-false rows, since `True > False`?

Comment: `min(True, False)` is `False`, `min(False, True)` is also `False`, `min(True, True)` is `True`, ...

Comment: Right. So (for anyone else who took longer to grok this) it returns `True` only for rows where each value is true; using this as an index returns only rows where `df_A > df_B` is true for every column.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one line code if you are interested.

```
df_A[(df_A > df_B)].dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

Here `df_A[(df_A > df_B)]` gives the output after matching true false either the value or `na`.

```
    one   two
0  20.0  11.0
1   NaN   9.0
2   NaN   NaN
```

Then we can drop the na values along the the 0 `axis` if there is at least `any`not a number value.

Comment: Nice answer! Another oneliner someone suggested is `df_A.loc[(df_A > df_B).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: Yes ! that one I would also prefer.